# onclick image part the image should change

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

I have written a code having image. If I hover on different part of image different images show up. I have also written a script to change the image onclick. But it is not working.

```
<img src="ch01ch01.png" width="453" id="image1" height="453" alt="Planets" usemap="#plmap">
<map name="plmap">
    <area shape="poly" coords="172,227,181,224,183,213,189,201,195,193,199,190,199,184,126,93,135,93,123,79,103,96,84,117,68,140,58,162,51,186,48,201,47,214,135,219,130,227,148,227,147,225,151,227,149,223,153,227,153,221,156,225,157,214,160,202,166,190,174,179,176,177,174,174,191,176,192,192,189,189,180,200,174,212,172,224,172,227" id="chapter12" alt="chap12" width="453" height="453"
         onmouseover="document.getElementById('image1').src='ch01ch12.png'" 
         onmouseout="document.getElementById('image1').src='ch01ch01.png'" onclick="changeImage()"/>
    <area shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229" alt="chap11" width="453" height="453"
         onmouseover="document.getElementById('image1').src='ch01ch11.png'" 
         onmouseout="document.getElementById('image1').src='ch01ch01.png'"/>
```

```
<script>
    function changeImage() {
        var temp = document.getElementById('image1');
        temp.src="ch01ch12.png";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a local path like `C:/image.png` because is not a recognized URI scheme. Instead put the html or js file in the same folder as the image and the src would be like this `src="image.png"`

Comment: where are your image and html or js located?
I tried your code and it works with some images that i put.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/mrus7LLp/
It works, just can you tell me in which folder do you hace those files?

Comment: I have them in same folder

Comment: Copy the code inside this fiddle and replace it in your file
https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/mr9z3vyq/

Comment: It is changing on mouse in and mouse out. not on click. I'm trying to use one image map multiple times. The idea is that you've got an picture with image map. You click on one area (there's a highlight on the image map), you get few links, you press one and and the picture is changed. The new picture is using the same image map as the original one (only the colors change in the image).